# Which combat sport makes more sense to be a super sport in a world, Peak Human MMA or Metahuman MMA?

Tags: science-fiction, humans, super-powers, worldbuilding-process, sports

In my world I'm trying to make a combat sport that is so super that normal humans can't join. But I'm going back and forth with Peak Humans and Metahumans.

To give you guys a clear definition of the terms.

Peak Human= Batman, Jason Bourne, Kill Bill, Fast and the Furious, Any action hero/normal human in fiction.

Metahuman: X Men, My Hero Academia, Spiderman, Hancock, any superhero/superhuman in fiction.

Peak Human MMA

Peak Human MMA has this perfect balance since all the fighters are still "normal humans". So they are all on the same level. The peak humans don't come with unique, vague, and broad superpowers that would cause a lot of different variables in a combat sport. Cough cough like the Metahumans.

But the problem with peak humans is that it's not easily recognizable. What I mean is. What makes peak human MMA different from normal human MMA? Don't get it twisted now. No real-world human can do the shit, Batman and John Wick do. But on the outside looking in Peak Human MMA just look like Normal human MMA to a casual. Of course on the inside peak, human MMA is different from normal human MMA.

But It's not like the average Joe automatically sperate a fictional human from a real-world human, to begin with. The normies view peak humans as real humans. Because peak humans are always portrayed as real humans in fiction for the most part. So that takes away my Super MMA field. Because the fighters are still seen as " real humans" by the majority. So my Peak Human MMA would just be another exaggerated Hollywood Action fight club Film.

Metahuman MMA

I feel like if don't take the Metahuman MMA route. I would be missing out on an amazing concept that is not seen that much in fiction. Outside Dragon Ball Z tournaments and Fighting Games like Mortal Kombat and Street Fighters. Doesn't matter if it's an original concept or not. MMA Fighters with superpowers is an awesome concept. Who wouldn't one see superpowers like Pyrokinesis, Telekinesis, Super Strength, etc in an MMA setting? That sounds like a great concept on paper.

But only on paper though. The problem with Metahuman MMA is there are way too many variables and moving parts. Because the Superpowers are too specific, vague, broad, and unique. Each Fighter will have their own power that operates with different rules and mechanics. Even if the powers are the same they can still work differently. I.E. not every Telepath, Speedsters, Element user, etc is the same. And don't forget about the Fighters that would have multiple different powers like Superman.

When it comes to power levels. Now that's a whole other variable. Power levels are too hard to define in a Metahuman MMA setting. Because the superpowers are too broad, vague, specific, and unique. In other words, any weak character with some type of tricky cheat code hax can defeat a stronger character with a much more bigger power level.

This meaning if Batman had pressure point powers that can work on anybody, he could defeat the Hulk. Even though Hulk has a much more higher power level. The broad/unique/specific/vague nature of superpowers gives a huge middle finger to power levels in Metahuman MMA setting lol.

In conclusion

I'm stuck between Peak Human MMA and Metahuman MMA. I don't what would be a better super combat sport for the world.

Comment: I'm voting to close. This is heavily opinionated and this cannot be answered. MMA is popular, but so was the show 'death battle' on youtube. Here anyone could potentially fight anyone, which lead to a lot of metahuman fights (as well as some human vs metahuman). They would be analysed and the one whi would likely win most engagements would win. From this we can see it is a matter of choice and opinion, not facts. One can like or dislike both even.

Comment: I agree with Trioxidane. You do not provide any constraints that could be used to reason why one type of MMA is better than the other. Thus, it is a matter of personal opinion. I would also suggest watching some Chinese animation targeting boys and male teenagers (there is a lot of donghua similar to Dragon Ball Z). It could be a good reference for fights among magic users.

Comment: There's also no reason provided why there should be only one type of combat sport. IRL we have boxing, karate, judo, taekwondo, wrestling. In fact, these sports are known to have multiple competitions per weight catagory, not to mention men's and women's. Then you have Para Taekwondo, with categories based on physical, visual or intellectual impairment. And then there's all the other non-Olympic combat sports.

Comment: "In my world I'm trying to make a combat sport that is so super that normal humans can't join."  You've just described the NBA.

Comment: Why all this concern about Money Market Accounts? (when using a fuzzy acronym, define it once, so the readers are on the same page)

Answer (score 4):

**Peak human makes more sense.**

While everyone talks about how batman would beat superman in a fight, when they say that they mean with tools or planning or whatever. Even characters who are strong like green lantern due to their power ring or whatever are only so strong on their own. Even characters like Daredevil are much much weaker physically than characters like the Hulk. Now, this problem does exist in real life to a degree. Most wrestling or MMA style fights have weight classes, to make sure that a guy who is just really big doesn't win every fight. The problem is that heroes have such a spread of power that likely every hero is in their own weight class.

On the other hand normal humans have a smaller spread so you can basically have heavyweight and light weight competitions. Also, if there are more peak humans than super humans and most super humans do hero stuff then peak humans might be the only ones who have enough people to organize these kinds of events.

Answer (score 3):

**Who is your audience?**

Metahumans battle royale means it is a comic book.  Readers want awesome powers, mountains exploding, amazing on top of amazing.  And then more of that.  Then monsters!  Supernatural aliens!  ONE PUUUNNCH!!  Interpersonal interactions and human scale problems are an afterthought and they save on your special effects budget.  But when I pick up a comic book with Metahuman Battle Royale I get impatient with too much of the chit chat.

Normal humans means you have a story that could be set in the real world, and readers interested in the human situations dealt with by those characters.  Your readers do not need ray guns. Bourne does sweet stuff but the story is moved by his human issues in the real world.  The movie Rocky is about a warrior but that is not what makes the movie great; it is a great story about a man.